# Android Material Design View State changes vs Elevation

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm trying to implement Material Design in my apps but I can't understand what is the difference to implement a shadow with `StateListAnimator` or assign an elevation to the views.

Below is the links about what im talking about:

[StateListAnimator](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#ViewState)
[Elevation](http://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Elevation)

What I'm seeing is that both can do the same thing, so why did they implement both in v5.0?

Answer (score 4):

StateListAnimator allows you to animate View properties including `elevation`. The default Button implementation uses StateListAnimator to handle `elevation` and `translationZ` changes in response to disabled and pressed state changes.

So instead of setting the elevation attribute, the default Button style uses the stateListAnimator attribute.

Here is a sample of what the XML for that looks like:

`res/animator/button_state_list_anim_material.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true">
        <set>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="translationZ"
                            android:duration="@integer/button_pressed_animation_duration"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_pressed_z_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
            <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                            android:duration="0"
                            android:valueTo="@dimen/button_elevation_material"
                            android:valueType="floatType"/>
        </set>
    </item>
    ...
```

Comment: Selector is not allowed in the anim directory.

Comment: This needs to go in the animator directory.

Comment: Is is possible to get full xml ?